# Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Operand type clash: text is incompatible with tinyint

Tags: sql, sql-server

when i try to execute the below query i am getting error such as

> Operand type clash: text is incompatible with tinyint

```
select First_Name,Last_Name,Active,
 CASE
    WHEN Active=1  THEN 'Active'
    ELSE 'INACTIVE'`
END as Status
from customer1;
```

table structure

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [Id] int
      ,[First_Name] varchar
      ,[Last_Name] varchar`
,[Active] varchar`
  FROM [master].[dbo].[customer]
```

Comment: You've tagged this for both Oracle and MySQL but the error appears to be coming from MySQL.  You've tagged this for PL/SQL but there does not appear to be any PL/SQL code.  Should those tags be removed or is there something about the question that does actually reference an Oracle database and the PL/SQL language?

Comment: Hi @JustinCave, can you please help me in resolving the error, i am very new to MSSQL

Comment: You've tagged the question for MySQL and Oracle.  Your comment now mentions Microsoft SQL Server.  Those are three very different databases with three very different SQL syntaxes.  Which one are you actually using?  If `Active` is a `varchar`, which seems like an odd choice for a column that presumably has only values '0' and '1' given the query, why are you comparing it to a number rather than a string?

Comment: Hi @JustinCave i am using MSSQL

Comment: @AmosNadar then please tag `sql-server` and remove the tags related to Oracle, PL/SQL and MySQL.

Comment: `[Active] varchar` column contains text which is not convertable to an integer value.

Comment: It appears that your `Active` column is of type **text** - a datatype that has been deprecated for almost 2 decades. Fix your schema. And NO ONE should be creating tables in the `MASTER` database. You are learning (have learned?) bad habits.

Comment: Try `WHEN Active='1'` with apostrophes

Answer (score 0):

You have this expression:

```
(CASE WHEN Active = 1 THEN 'Active'
      ELSE 'INACTIVE'`
 END) as Status
```

`Active` has been defined as a string but is being compared to a number.  Hence, `Active` is being converted into a number.  Presumably, you intend:

```
(CASE WHEN Active = '1' THEN 'Active'
      ELSE 'INACTIVE'`
 END) as Status
```

The error is arising because you have non-numeric values in the column.   You can see what these are using a query:

```
select active
from customer1
group by active;
```